# Are infinite linear combinations that converge in a Banach space uniquely represented?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a Banach space, and $(x_n)$ is a sequence of linearly independent elements of X, then is the following true? If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n = 0_X,$ then $a_n = 0$ for every $n$.

Thank you.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by *"linearly independent"*.  If you're referring to the *algebraic definition*, then the answer is no.

Comment: I mean "linearly independent" in the sense that every finite subset is linearly independent.

Comment: Then indeed the answer is no, as I'll clarify in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the usual definition of linearly independent, this fails to be true.

For example: define a sequence in $X = \ell^2$ as follows: for $n,k \in \Bbb N$,
$$
x_1(k) = \frac{1}{k}\\
x_n(k) = \begin{cases}
1 & k = n-1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \quad \text{for } n \geq 2
$$
Confirm that this sequence is linearly independent.  Nevertheless, we have
$$
x_1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac 1{n-1}\right)x_n = 0
$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.